# Azure function Python - error "binding type(s) 'blobTrigger' are not registered"

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to run an Azure function locally on my Mac and getting the following error: `The binding type(s) 'blobTrigger' are not registered. Please ensure the type is correct and the binding extension is installed.`

I'm working with `Python 3.6.8` and have installed `azure-functions-core-tools` using homebrew (`brew tap azure/functions; brew install azure-functions-core-tools`).

Setup my `local.settings.json` file with the expected configuration, so function should be listening to the correct storage container hosted in azure.

Im certain I have not changed any code or configuration files since it was working last week.

host.json file contains:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[1.*, 2.0.0)"
  }
}
```

function.json file contains:

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "xmlblob",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "<directory>/{name}",
      "connection": "AzureStorageAccountConnectionString"
    }
  ]
}
```

requirements.txt file contains:

```
azure-cosmos==3.1.0
azure-functions-worker==1.0.0b6
azure-storage==0.36.0
azure-storage-blob==2.0.1
xmljson==0.2.0
xmlschema==1.0.11
```

Then I run the following commands in my terminal:

```
1) pip install -r requirements.txt
2) source .env/bin/activate
3) func host start
```

I then get the following error:

```
<Application name>: The binding type(s) 'blobTrigger' are not registered. Please ensure the type is correct and the binding extension is installed.
```

Comment: any luck? :\ I am getting `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: Im not sure what causes this issue, but I fixed my problem by uninstalling python dependencies, then python 3.6.8, uninstalled azure-functions-core-tools and finally uninstall all versions of the .NET Core 2.2 SDK (in that order). Then I reinstalled everything in the reverse order for macOS and now it works locally. It would be nice to know why this happened?

Answer (score 1):

You have done everything correct by the looks of it, but you need to have the dotnet core framework and runtime installed locally in order to execute the trigger.

For me on Ubuntu, I followed [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-package-manager-ubuntu-1804). Once installed I was able to trigger a blob function locally.

For Mac, I would [take a look here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download) about installing dotnot core.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because there was something wrong with the bundle that it had downloaded and cached. In addition to the error message, earlier on in the log was a warning about not being able to load the Extension Bundle and a few lines earlier the log shows the path it's loading the bundle from, like C:\Users<redacted>\AppData\Local\Temp\Functions\ExtensionBundles\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle. I deleted the ExtensionBundles folder and it re-downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

I followed [nathan shumoogum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11582481/nathan-shumoogum) solution that he describes in a comment on another answer of this question. It worked.

The process is:
Uninstall python dependencies, then python 3.6.8, uninstall azure-functions-core-tools and finally uninstall all versions of the .NET Core 2.2 SDK (in that order). Then reinstall everything in the reverse order for macOS.

Answer (score -2):

Make sure you have the Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage nuget package installed.

[image]

If you do it from portal , it prompted to install the extension.

[image]

Comment: does this help with (i) local, (ii) python and (iii) macOS?

Comment: No it doesn't nuget is for the .NET cli not Python cli if Im not mistaken